# php header() not working on a ssl website

Tags: php, ssl

i have a website with ssl , and in my website i used php header() to redirect after user login, successful query, etc. and it is working on my local host. but when i uploaded the site in my hosting with ssl certificate, the header() was not working. why?? any help or idea would be appreciated.

php scripts which are not working:

```
<?php

session_start(); 

if(!isset($_SESSION['admin'])){ 
    header("location: index.php?You_Must_Login");
    exit();
}

?>

header("Location:create_itinerary.php?Item_Added_Succesfully");
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: whats with error_reporting? i didn't got u.

Comment: see if anything comes of it.

Comment: Usually this is because the header already has an output... are you sure nothing is being called before this file / this point?

Comment: naah... no hope it seems.

Comment: yeah iam sure. try www.andamanexoticholidays.com/admin

Comment: try placing the 2nd header into the else statement and remove all blank row

Comment: the 2nd header also seems to have problem,it gives an 404, or is it admin/create_itinerary.php....

Comment: <? ob_start(); ?> and <? ob_flush(); ?> worked for me...

Comment: The code of yours seems legit. If you have no other includes above the code, then you can try to check if there is a BOM character in your file. Of course then, the ob_start will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Add `<? ob_start(); ?>` at starting before 1st `<?php` and add `<? ob_flush(); ?>` at last after `?>`